# how to pass asset image from app to a package in flutter?

Tags: flutter, pub.dev

I'm trying to create a package that contains some custom widgets. the plan is ill import this package and ill just start using those widgets in my project. something like a UI component library. for this, in a widget, I need to pass an image file to decorate a Container. and I want to pass this image file from my flutter project to the flutter package. but not as a widget but as a file path.

so I created a widget like this

```dart
class ContainerDeco extends StatelessWidget {
  const ContainerDeco(this.src, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final String src;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage(src),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but now when I call this widget from my project file it's not working.
here is my sample code from the project file

```dart
ContainerDeco('assets/images/lockup_flutter_horizontal.png',);
```

here is my project `pubspec.yaml` asset import

```yaml
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/
```

Comment: can you share with us the error message please

Comment: its shows nothing! no error. but the image is not showing basically.

Comment: what if you try to set the image inside the container and set width and height 100 for example, what is the result if you try to do that? A white square or nothing also?

Comment: oh, I'm so trash. there was no size for the container. thanks, bro. it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

if i get the question, you want to pass some assets from project to a package or plugin, for this you cant set the path of assets but you can user rootbundels

in project =>

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

String assetPath = 'assets/my_asset_file.svg';
var data = (await rootBundle.load(assetPath));
```

in the package or plugin

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

WIdget loadAsset(ByteData assetData) async {
  Uint8List svgBytes = assetData.buffer.asUint8List();

  
  // Do something with the asset data
  return SvgPicture.memory(svgBytes );
}
```